# Why does consuming from kafka not finish in cloudera but finishes in hortonworks?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TopicIngester {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]") // remove this later
      .appName("Ingester")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.read
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:6667" /*my.cluster.com:9092 in case of cloudera*/)
      .option("subscribe", "test")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
      .load()
      .write
      .parquet("/user/maria_dev/test")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

When I run it in the hortonworks sandbox everything works fine. All available data is read from the `test` topic and saved into the `/user/maria_dev/test` folder.

I also have a topic with the same name on my cloudera cluster, and for some reason it gets stuck at `.parquet("/path/to/folder")` and never finishes, as if it is waiting for more data forever or something.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a Kafka or Spark configuration mismatch... What does the Spark UI say?

Comment: Note: Kafka HDFS Connector or Pinterest's Secor project can both write Parqeut from Kafka... This stops you from having to "reinvent the wheel" and learning how to write Spark code for this simple use case

Comment: @cricket_007 it says nothing, and I can't even debug this properly in intellij. It just gets stuck and I can't even step into methods.

Comment: @cricket_007 how do I even check kafka version in cloudera?

Comment: You find the page for your installation version - For example, the latest is here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_packaging.html